# Fatal Error in R (only after multiple calls)

Tags: r, fatal-error, lapply

I coded some concatenated functions with multiple `lapply`. The functions work, but I always encounter a Fatal Error after exactly the fifth time calling the function. What could possibly be a source of that? I don't think it's memory: it takes 8 secs to execute the function (once). I also tried to include `gc()` in the function and to execute the code on a different computer (also a Mac and little older R). Nothing helped.

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "3.2"

$year
[1] "2016"

$month
[1] "10"

$day
[1] "31"

$svn rev
[1] "71607"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)"

$nickname
[1] "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
```

#### EXAMPLE

```
require(xts)
stoplossx = function(yy) { 
  populate = function(x) { 
    if(unique(is.na(x))=='TRUE') return(x)
    naseries=cbind(x,NA)[,2]
    where=which(x<(yy))[1]
    if(!is.na(where)) return(na.locf(cbind(x[1:where],naseries)[,1]))
    if(is.na(where)) return(x)
  }
  populate2 = function(zz) {
    do.call(cbind, lapply(as.list(zz), populate))
  }

dailyip=readRDS(gzcon(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kfxg1vi1s6hv6cg/dailyip.rds")))
  #dailyip=readRDS('~/Dropbox/MS/dailyip.rds') 
  long=ifelse(dailyip==1,1,NA)
  short=ifelse(dailyip==-1,-1,NA)
  dailyrx=readRDS(gzcon(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/of47enf79ugkq8c/dailyrx.rds")))
  #dailyrx=readRDS('~/Dropbox/MS/dailyrx.rds') 
  dailyrx2=do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dailyrx, 'months'), cumsum)) 

  long_split <- split(long*dailyrx2, 'months')
  short_split <- split(short*dailyrx2, 'months')

  # split into month, and then into columns in populate2
  stoploss_l <- do.call(rbind, lapply(long_split, populate2))
  stoploss_s <- do.call(rbind, lapply(short_split, populate2))

  rx4b <- xts(rowMeans(apply.monthly(stoploss_l, last), na.rm=T)+
              rowMeans(apply.monthly(stoploss_s, last), na.rm=T), 
              index(apply.monthly(stoploss_l, last)))
  gc()
  return(rx4b)
}

stoplossx(-0.01)
stoplossx(-0.02)
stoplossx(-0.03)
stoplossx(-0.04)
stoplossx(-0.05)
```

Comment: `traceback()` will tell you where approx. the error came from. Insert `browser()` into the first line of your function and step through it by pressing `c`. Once you're on "loop" 5, start stepping through the function 1 line at a time and inspect elements and see what can be done. Without a reproducible example, this is really not answerable.

Comment: I tried the browser() idea but then I get the Fatal Error right away. I will update the question with the reproducible function code

Comment: Please also indicate where you placed the `browser()` call. Can you verify that you reran the function definition before using it? What does `traceback()` say (please don't paste output in the comment section)?

Comment: Dear Roman, I tried various placements. Sometimes the function runs through, sometimes again the fatal error (and no tracking possible?). Would it be possible for you to run the script on your computer and see if the same happens? (I made the data available from within the function) I really don't know what to do

Comment: When I run this, I get an error `Error in long * dailyrx2 : non-conformable arrays` when creating `long_split` because array dimensions don't match up. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romunov/54e8ed40c9aab3b1688705a742e143e7) on how to make your workflow in order to easily debug the code. Once you have it nailed down with no errors, you can wrap it in a function. Make sure you don't repeat fixed steps every time (like fetching of what I presume is static data).

Comment: Thanks Roman! I have checked your gist but I can run it without errors :-( And thanks for the suggestion! I have put only the last part into the function, and now it works. Still don't understand why this would cause fatal error...